# How can I display the familly name first in the addressbook on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contacts

I just want to display it in the format

Famillyname, Firstname

Doe, John

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's possible at the moment

There is a bug about sorting
https://bugs.launchpad.net/address-book-app/+bug/1215373

It might be worth opening another one with your request
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/address-book-app/+filebug

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I filed a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/address-book-app/+bug/1439140